# Angular pass component as method parameter (ngComponentOutlet) issue

Tags: angular

I am loading some components at runtime like this:

```
load(): any {
  this.comp = OneComponent;
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="comp"></ng-container>
<button (click)="load()">Load Component One</button>
```

The above works but I want to use the same method to call multiple components...so I want to do something like this:

```
loadComponent(comp): any {
  this.comp = comp;
}
```

But when I try calling it like this:

```
<button (click)="load('OneComponent')">Load Component</button> <!-- This doesn't work -->
```

The above I cannot do ... I know it's a string but I cannot add:

`(click)="load(OneComponent)"` either.

So, how do I do this?

Comment: Do you have any errors? As it seems you are not passing the component instance instead just a name which won't render the component. Can you add more code?

Comment: as per [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)`NgComponentOutlet` must receive  Type reference and not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to provide the actual component as the parameter to `*ngComponentOutlet`. At the moment you're sending only the string `'OneComponent'`.

Try the following

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
compMapping = {
  "one": OneComponent,
  "two": TwoComponent,
  ...
};

loadComponent(comp): any {
  if (!!this.compMapping[comp]) {
    this.comp = this.compMapping[comp];
  }
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<button (click)="load('one')">Load Component</button>
```